# Vb.net how to merge column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagrid

I'm having a problem on my datagridview. How can I merge the row if column2 and column3 are the same?

For example:

```
Col 1| Col2| Col3|

    2| Mars|Regular

    3| Mars|Regular
```

How can I merge it into one column only?

Comment: You could order your data and test the previous row with the current one and delete it if it matchs.

Comment: that's what ive done i want to know how can i do after putting the value on datagrid there will be a msgbox that will warn the user

Comment: You can create a Sub that will loop your rows and test it. When it matchs you add a MsgBox with the merged rows or values and if it does not match it continue with the next row

Comment: i dont know the code for merging

Comment: You didn't understand what i said. It is not a merge, it will just find if two rows are identicals and delete one in this case.

Comment: In your given example, you need to get **2|Mars|Regular** or **2,3|Mars|Regular** ?

Comment: 5|mars|Regular
2 and 3 will add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should answer your question :

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Populate manually your datagridview
    Dim row As Object() = New Object() {2, "Mars", "Regular"}
    dtgv.Rows.Add(row)
    row = New Object() {3, "Mars", "Regular"}
    dtgv.Rows.Add(row)
    row = New Object() {10, "Earth", "Regular"}
    dtgv.Rows.Add(row)

    ' Try to merge rows
    For i = 0 To dtgv.RowCount - 1
        merge(i)
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub merge(ByVal row As Integer)
    Dim planet As Boolean = False
    Dim regularity As Boolean = False

    ' If planets are identicals
    If dtgv.Rows(row).Cells(1).Value = dtgv.Rows(row + 1).Cells(1).Value Then
        planet = True
    End If

    ' Same
    If dtgv.Rows(row).Cells(2).Value = dtgv.Rows(row + 1).Cells(2).Value Then
        regularity = True
    End If

    ' Merge
    If planet = True And regularity = True Then
        ' Sum up index
        dtgv.Rows(row).Cells(0).Value = dtgv.Rows(row).Cells(0).Value + dtgv.Rows(row + 1).Cells(0).Value
        ' Remove one row
        dtgv.Rows.RemoveAt(row + 1)
        ' Message to warn there is a merge
        MsgBox("Rows " & row & " and " & row + 1 & " merged !")
    End If
End Sub
```

Only the two first rows will match because the third one have a different planet.

Comment: Did you know you can address the dgv cells by x,y? e.g. `dtgv(colNum, rowNum).value`  May return `Nothing` You can avoid testing for Nothing by appending "" or adding 0 e.g. `dtgv(colNum, rowNum).value & ""` Saves a lot of typing.